# Using multiple versions of a dependency in the same project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, csproj

One of my clients wants to port an old version of a SAML 2.0 library (ComponentSpace.SAML2) to the newest version. As part of this job, I'm required to write unit tests which verify that the generated SAML messages match between the old and new versions of this library.

So I am trying to write a test project which is able to use both versions of that library, instantiate some "equivalent" objects in both versions, and verify that the generated SAML (XML) messages have some matching attributes between the different versions. Both versions of the library are added to the project as **DLL files** (rather than Nuget packages).

I've seen many solutions which involve using [extern aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias), and these seem to be the way to approach and solve this problem.

Problem is that I am getting this warning once the project gets compiled:

```
warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between
"ComponentSpace.Saml2, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=16647a1283418145"
and "ComponentSpace.SAML2, Version=2.2.0.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c51d97b3a0a8ff9".

Choosing "ComponentSpace.Saml2, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=16647a1283418145" arbitrarily.
[C:\my-test-project\TestsMultiVersionLib.csproj]
```

And when I run the program, I get the following runtime error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'ComponentSpace.SAML2.Protocols.SAMLResponse' from assembly 'ComponentSpace.Saml2, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=16647a1283418145'.
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args)
```

I have managed to write this very simplified code to simulate the error:

```
// Program.cs
extern alias Saml2Net4;
extern alias Saml2Net6;

var oldObj = new Saml2Net4.ComponentSpace.SAML2.Protocols.SAMLResponse();
var newObj = new Saml2Net6.ComponentSpace.Saml2.Protocols.SamlResponse();
```

And here's my project's CSPROJ file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>    

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ComponentSpace.SAML2, Version=2.2.0.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c51d97b3a0a8ff9">
      <HintPath>lib/ComponentSpace.SAML2.Net4.dll</HintPath>
      <Aliases>Saml2Net4</Aliases>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ComponentSpace.Saml2, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=16647a1283418145">
      <HintPath>lib/ComponentSpace.SAML2.dll</HintPath>
      <Aliases>Saml2Net6</Aliases>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I have also tried adding `<Private>true</Private>` and `<SpecificVersion>true</SpecificVersion>` to the `<Reference...>` tags, as suggested in other answers I've stumbled upon. In any case, the build process seems to only be copying `ComponentSpace.SAML2.dll` to the output directory (not including `ComponentSpace.SAML2.Net4.dll` to the output directory at all).

Does anyone know what I might do to fix the compilation warning and the runtime error? What am I missing here?

Comment: I'd try to add these dependencies to different projects and use `PrivateAssets="All"` (not sure it's legal for assembly references).

Comment: Or try to load them as plugins: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support